# Is there a way to pass a string containing non-ASCII characters to a test?

Tags: c++, unicode, cmake, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to check if my code correctly handles commandline arguments with non-ASCII characters.

I have this code in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_test(NAME core/application/unicode COMMAND core/application "")
```

But when I run ctest from Qt Creator, I get this output:

```
Test command: core\application.exe "ðŸŒ"
```

Which is not what I want. How do I correctly pass this character (or any Unicode string, really) to the test on the commandline. This should work on Windows and Unix.

Comment: Write a one-line script to execute the command with the appropriately-encoded parameter. Execute the script.

Comment: If the terminal is UTF-8, I guess `add_test(NAME core/application/unicode COMMAND core/application "\xF0\x9F\x8D\x8C")` should do it

Comment: You have to use 2 sets of code because "application.exe" expects the argument to be UTF-16 or UTF-8, depending on OS. Maybe Qt has a solution for this, you should add Qt tag to your question!

Comment: `"ðŸŒ"` is what you get if you read the UTF-8 encoding for that banana, `"\xf0\x9f\x8d\x8c"`, as ISO-8859-1 (note that `U+008D` is a control character). On what platform did you get that output?

Comment: @roeland that was on Windows, both in the MSYS2 bash shell as in cmd.exe.

Comment: @Barmak I am interpreting the arguments inside my program in an OS dependent way to handle this, just like Qt does. The problem here is getting CMake to pass them correctly to my program on all OSes.

Comment: @Sam might work, but will also carry the burden of having at least two scripts that do the same thing (one for Windows and one for others, i.e. UTF-8 shells).

Comment: I think your problem is *printing* that text. The console on Windows internally uses UCS-2, so it cannot display that  banana (or any other character above U+FFFF). You can still verify if your string contains that character by other means, for example you can check if `theString.toUcs4()[0]` equals `127820`.

Comment: @roeland, that's the thing, the verification in application.exe fails.

Comment: OK, lots of other possibilities. Can you include the contents of your CMAKE file and .cpp file?